# Unable To Update_View_Delete Modal Dialog Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need help...i'm trying to make an insert/update/view/delete form using PHP and modal dialog bootstrap.
i'm managed to do insert process. But unable to update, view and delete from bootstrap modal dialog.

db connection&process

```
<?php
define('host', 'localhost');
define('user', 'root');
define('password', '');
define('db_name', 'testing');
$connect = NEW mysqli(host,user,password,db_name) or die (mysqli_error());
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$name = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$address = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
if($SQL)
{
?>
<script>
alert('Data Inserted!.');
        window.location.href='crud.php';
   </script>
<?php
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
{
$SQL = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_employee WHERE id=".$_GET['edit']);
$view= $SQL->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
}
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$SQL = $connect->query("UPDATE tbl_employee SET Nama='".$_POST['name']."', Email='".$_POST['email']."', Address='".$_POST['address']."' WHERE id=".$_GET['edit']);
if($SQL)
{
?>
<script>
alert('Data Updated.');
        window.location.href='crud.php';
   </script>
       <?php
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $SQL = $connect->query("DELETE FROM tbl_employee WHERE id=".$_GET['delete']);
if($SQL)
{
?>
<script>
alert('Data Deleted!.');
        window.location.href='crud.php';
   </script>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

form

```
<div id="employee_table">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th width=10%>#</th>
            <th width=60%>Employee Name</th>
            <th width=20%>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            @$no++;
         ?>    
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" name="view" value="View" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" 
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view" />
            <input type="button" name="view" value="Update" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs 
            update_data" 
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update" />
            <input type="button" name="view" value="Delete" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs 
            delete_data" 
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </table>
        </div>
```

view modal dialog

```
<div id="view" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4>Employee Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">
        <form method="post" id="insert_form" action="">
<label>Employee name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['update'])){ echo $view['1']; } ?>" readonly="" />
<br>
<label>Employee Address</label>
<textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['update'])){ echo $view['2']; } ?>"readonly=""></textarea>

        </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[employee info unable to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTQ1J.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not view employee detail like this.

Use ajax call for show detail.

Where you pass the id which you assign in view button???

If you are beginner in PHP, Check below link.

It will help you in CRUD operations.

Tutorial link : http://www.itechempires.com/2016/03/php-mysql-crud-create-read-update-delete-operations-using-jquery/

Demo link : http://demos.itechempires.com/php-mysql-crud-operations/

OR use this:

```
<input type="button" name="view" value="View" onclick="view_data('<?=$row['name']?>','<?=$row['address']?>')" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data"
                     data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view" />

<script type="text/javascript">
     function view_data(name,address) {
          $('#view input[name=name]').val(name);
          $('#view input[name=address]').val(address);
     }

</script>
```